# Comments for columns and tables in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, comments, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am new to using MySQL workbench.
Just wanted to understand how do I add comments to columns and tables that I am creating in the UI itself?

```
System Information:
Windows 8 Enterprise, 64 Bit
MySQL Workbench 6.2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly - you want to know this?

[image]

Comment: Ohh great. Thanks a bunch. The little down arrow to the right side did the trick.